# Sync app with server in background

Tags: ios, core-data, background-process, nstimeinterval

I am building an app that requires that I look twice a day for new records in a dynamic json file and save it in core data and update the apps badge count. So how would I go about getting that app to run the update function in the background so the user does not have to open it?

Comment: Have you tried searching and checking similar questions and documentations?

Answer (score 0):

Running processes in the background is standard stuff and very easy in the case of fetching something from a server.

The normal concurrency APIs are calls like `dispacth_async()` and the like, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

However, for your simple task use `NSURLConnection` which by default is asynchronous and also very simple to use. See the documentation for [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) and for the more difficult to find [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011348).

Of course, if you want the app to fetch data twice a day even if it is not active, you will have to ask user permission via [push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).